# Authentication using Google_Oauth2Service API

Tags: php, google-authentication

I have the following login code:

- JS Login controller:

  ```
  token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
  Ext.php.Users.login(token, function(n) {
  if (Ext.isString(n)) window.location = n;
  else if (n != null) {
      app.user = user;
      r.add({
          id: 0,
          email: t.email,
          password: t.password,
          roles: user.Roles,
          defaultrole: user.DefaultRole
      });
      e.loadMainView("userHome");
  }
  });
  ```
- PHP login function:

  ```
  public function login($token) {
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);

      if (!empty($token)) {
          $token = base64_decode($token);
          $client->setAccessToken($token);

          if (!$client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
              $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();

              $email = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

              $u = $this->getByEmail($email);

              if ($u != null) return $u;
          }

          $this->logout($token);
      }

      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      return $authUrl;
  }
  ```
- In my google/config.php file:

  ```
  ...
  'oauth2_redirect_uri' => getLoginCallBackUrl(),
  ...
  ```
- That function, in the same file:

  ```
  function getLoginCallBackUrl() {
      $pageURL = 'http';
      //if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
      $pageURL .= "://";
      if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
          $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
      } else {
          $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
      }

      return substr($pageURL,0,strpos($pageURL,'/api/') + 5) .'login_callback.php';
  }
  ```

Basically, after I try to log in I am asked for Google Authentication. I pass it for a test user, and I get redirected back to my web application: but the token, although initially loaded, is discarded upon the application fully loading and I cannot log in. Trying to login again merely redoes the google authentication without success.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I got it to work. The code above is correct. I had a typo with one of my fields after a schema change. I will be leaving the question up with the details in the hopes that the code may help somebody, somewhere.

Comment: You may want to anwer your own question to MARK it as answered rather than writing SOLVED into the title. Cheers'

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I'll accept it as soon as I able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've written in the edit, the code above is actually correct (although there is a bit of controller login JS code not shown here). The issue was a field typo after a schema change.